# Прелоладер загрузки,подскажите пожалуйста)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, vue.js

Всем привет,я загружаю фотку на страницу,как мне вместо  console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);  отобразить прелоадер загрузки? Подскажите

```
data() {
        return {
          selectedFile: null,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        onFileSelected(event) {
          this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        },
        onUpload() {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append(this.selectedFile.name, this.selectedFile);
          formData.append('name', 'files');
          axios.post('api/v1/files/create', {
            count: 1,
          }, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`,
            },
          })
            .then(() => axios.put('api/v1/files', formData, {
              headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`,
              },

              onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                console.log(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
              },
            }));
        },
      },
```

Comment: закиньте в `data` переменную `progress`, и присваивайте ей значения, а сам лоудер в шаблоне рисуйте

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    progress: 0
  },
  mounted: function(){
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.progress++;
      if (this.progress >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 100);
  }
})
```

```css
.progress {
  background: wheat;
}
.progress-bar {
  background: lightblue;
  transition: width .1s;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="progress" v-if="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" :style="{ width: progress+'%'}">{{ progress }}%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```